# SSRS Parameters Value in Ascending Order

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have an SSRS report with a parameter called `Transfer Id`:

[image: Parameter]

The options in this list are not ordered - how can I sort this list ascending or descending based on the displayed values?

The `Transfer Id` parameter value is dependent on other parameters in the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your available parameter values are being specified explicitly (using the "Specify values" option on the Available Values page of the Parameter Properties dialog, then you can set the order of the options explicitly by selecting an available value and using the Up and Down arrow buttons - as per [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283107.aspx):

> The order of items you see in this list determines the order that the
>   user sees them in the drop-down list. To change the order of an item
>   in the list, click a **Value** or **Label** text box to select the item, and
>   then use the up and down arrow buttons to move the item higher or
>   lower in the list.

If your options are the result of a DataSet, then you can set the ordering in that DataSet's query with an `ORDER BY` clause. If no ordering is specified on the DataSet, the values will be sorted alphabetically.