# PowerBi Report Builder (Paginated Report) Parameter Items Sorting

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, parameters, powerbi

In PowerBI Report Builder (Paginated Report), How to SORT parameter items?. For example, How to sort "Month Names" parameter items according to their chronology instead of alphabetically? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS Parameters Value in Ascending Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157098/ssrs-parameters-value-in-ascending-order)

Comment: That answer is confusing - it answer a different, unasked question with most of it and at the end adds the actual answer - use `ORDER BY` in the parameter's query.